# Сложная выборка из двух баз данных

Tags: mysql

У нас есть 4 базы данных:

1. База мест (Допустим "Ресторан Токио")
2. База типов мест (Например "Рестораны")
3. База назначений этого места (Например "Организация свадеб")
4. И база привязки типов и назначений к самому месту.

Структура такова:

- `id`
- `place_id`
- `type_id`
- `purpose_id`

Одно место может иметь несколько типов и назначений.

Чтобы выбрать из базы места с определенным типом, можно воспользоваться запросом:

```
SELECT site_places.* FROM site_places INNER JOIN site_place_data ON site_places.id = site_place_data.place_id AND site_place_data.purpose_id = '2'
```

Аналогичным образом можно достать с определенным назначением.

```
SELECT site_places.* FROM site_places INNER JOIN site_place_data ON site_places.id = site_place_data.place_id AND site_place_data.type_id = '2'
```

Но как достать из базы места определенного типа **И** назначения? База примерно выглядит так:
[image]

То есть в одной строке не может быть и `type_id` и `purpose_id`.

Помогите, пожалуйста, о, великие кодеры! Буду безмерно благодарен)

Comment: база у вас одна, таблиц несколько. проведите декомпозицию вашей развязочной таблицы. их должно быть две, сразу увидите, что должно быть два join'а на тип и на назначение.

Comment: @yura_ivanov в том-то и веселье, что объединяющая таблица одна. Я думал, какими нибудь Count() попробовать сделать. Но не уверен, что-то либо выйдет. Можно попробовать одну таблицу "раздвоить" с помощью AS. Но как это все сделать, я не знаю.

Comment: веселья тут нет. у вас неверная структура данных. но в любом случае надо "раздвоить" join, как вы сказали, об этом я выше и написал. должно быть два join'а. псевдоним таблицы задается так: `table_name as tn`, дальше идет `on...` и так далее. напишите ваши два join'а друг за другом (не забывая про псевдонимы), все получится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

честно говоря, немного сумбурно спрошено, (измените в вопросе - скорей всего у вас не 4 базы данных а 4 таблицы одной базы данных),

как решение - сделайте join 3х таблиц, в чем проблема?

```
SELECT p.*, d.*, t.*
FROM site_places p 
INNER JOIN site_place_data d ON p.id = d.place_id 
INNER JOIN site_place_types t ON d.place_id = t.id 
WHERE d.purpose_id = 2 AND t.type_id = 1;
```

Comment: работа за автора в этом проблема

Comment: Да, 4 таблицы. Ваш пример мне помог. Спасибо, разобрался.

Comment: Это просто трупор. Сделать надо, на не получается. Вот и обратился за помощью

Comment: @vital_viza ничего страшного - все учатся и самый хороший способ это практика